# How important is Differential Geometry for Number Theory?

Tags: number-theory, differential-geometry, soft-question

The title pretty much says it. To elaborate slightly, I am, of course, aware of the huge role played by Algebraic Geometry in Number Theory but I'm not so sure about Differential Geometry. I would be very interested to hear from any experts in the field.

Many thanks!

Comment: See [New Geometric Methods in Number Theory and Automorphic Forms](https://www.msri.org/programs/280).

Comment: My experience is that pretty much everything is important for Number Theory. So far, I haven't ever actually applied any DG in my NT research, and couldn't point to any specific applications, but that's probably just a comment on my own limitations.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the ways one uses differential geometry in number theory are just not as directly visible as some of the other areas NT utilizes--such as abstract algebra--which makes it more difficult to see its usefulness. I find the most use of the subject in the application of [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) to the subject.

Of course, there are degenerate cases:  [Minkowski theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers) is a rich area of number theory that uses geometry extensively to study solutions to Diophantine problems. Naturally some of the convex bodies involved can (though in practice aren't always too bad) get somewhat complicated or defy simple computations of volume, which of course is a classical question in differential topology. I call it "degenerate" because much of it is linear algebra, but in practice some of the convex bodies actually require the topology, so including it seemed apropos since the question is pretty open-ended.

---

[Grigory Margulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Margulis) is a genius who has used methods from the analysis on groups like the [special linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group) to prove [results on quadratic forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheim_conjecture). He also has proven important results on [arithmeticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28discrete_subgroup%29#Arithmetic_lattices) by analyzing these groups from a topological and dynamical point of view.

---

Techniques in [ergodic theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory) are used in [Diophantine approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) regularly. Classical results include the [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) of points $[n\alpha]$ in the interval $[0,1]$ iff $\alpha$ is irrational. [Horocycle flow](http://math.nyu.edu/~venkatesh/lec7.pdf) is intimately related to [hyperbolic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) in a way which explicitly utilizes the differential structure on the space and the metric on the upper half-plane.

---

The structure on $SL_n(\Bbb R)$ especially is used to establish subgroups which generate the entire group, which comes from general facts about Lie groups, established using differential topology rules. These structure theorems are used over and over in the proofs. [Amir Mohammadi](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/amir/) is a student of the aforementioned Margulis who is doing excellent work in this area using such ideas.

---

And of course, I would be remiss not to mention the amazingly-named [ping-pong lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma). It neatly plays the group theory and geometry off of one another to prove results about each using information from the other.

---

I think if you're expecting anything particularly complex, you'll be disappointed as is common in most cross-uses in areas, it's not usually the cutting edge in both fields working on the same problems, but certainly they show up and are important.