# Is there a branch of mathematics that combines symplectic geometry and number theory?

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, symplectic-geometry, research

I am trying to find a research topic to study. I really enjoy symplectic and contact geometry but I am also interested in number theory, especially diophantine approximation, so it would be nice if I could work on a branch that combines both, is there such a branch or even a topic?

Comment: In general, number theory uses a lot of geometry, e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063917/how-important-is-differential-geometry-for-number-theory), or [this program](https://www.msri.org/programs/280). If you only want Diophantine approximation, this may be very narrow, and would not really involve geometry.